# How do you merge a two dimensional and a three dimensional list together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, merge

I'm having trouble figuring out a code to write that will merge a two dimensional list to a three dimensional list. For example, "a" is two dimensional list and "b" is three dimensional list that i would like to merge them two together and sort in order. If this is possible can this be done with witting a list comprehension? For another example here is my two list below.

```
a = [[7, 28],[28],[28]]
b = [[[3, 9],[3, 9],[3, 9]],[[3, 4],[4, 7],[4, 7]],[[7, 11],[3, 11],[3, 7, 12]]]
```

I would like my result to be

```
c = [[[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 9, 28]],
     [[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7,28]],
     [[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28]]]
```

Comment: Is it true, that the second level is always of same length?

Comment: Yes . Do u think it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
c = [[sorted(i+x) for i in y] for x, y in zip(a,b)]

print(c)
#[[[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 9, 28]],[[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7,28]],[[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you fancy a oneliner:

```
result = [[sorted(i+x) for i in y] for x, y in zip(a,b)]

print (result)

#[[[3, 9, 7, 28], [3, 9, 7, 28], [3, 9, 7, 28]], [[3, 4, 28], [4, 7, 28], [4, 7, 28]], [[7, 11, 28], [3, 11, 28], [3, 7, 12, 28]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
c = [[sorted(i+k) for k in j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

**Output** :

```
[[[3, 7, 9, 28], [3, 7, 9, 28], [3, 7, 9, 28]], 
 [[3, 4, 28], [4, 7, 28], [4, 7, 28]], 
 [[7, 11, 28], [3, 11, 28], [3, 7, 12, 28]]]
```

Here is another way without one-liner :

```
c = b[:]
for i,j in zip(a,c):
    for k in j:
        k.extend(i)
        k.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

another 1-liner, using `enumerate` instead of `zip`:

```py
c = [[sorted(s1+a[i]) for s1 in s0] for i, s0 in enumerate(b)]
```